# With Firebase can I track something like which percentage of users uses Night Mode versus Day Mode?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a dark theme in my app, is it possible to track the split between Dark vs Light with Firebase? I know I could track something like "night" or "day" on launch but it'd just be a total number of events rather than an easily digestible split right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to understand some preference the user has expressed, you'll want to use a [user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties) for that.

> You can set Analytics User Properties to describe the users of your app. You can analyze behaviors of various user segments by applying these properties as filters to your reports.